# How to display date in date field with SAP B1 SDK?

Tags: sapb1

I know how to display value in field of matrix in SAP B1 SDK, but I don't know how to display date in date field.

The variable `FromDate` contains a date from database and I want to display it in date field.

Below VBS code failed:

```
mtx2.Columns.Item("C_1_5").Cells.Item(mtx2.RowCount).Specific.string = FromDate
```

Below VBS code displays nothing in the field:

```
mtx2.Columns.Item("C_1_5").Cells.Item(mtx2.RowCount).Specific.string _
    = Format(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Does anyone know how to set the value of a date field?

Comment: What language are you using, VB or C#? How do you have your matrix fields defined? Are you getting an error message? What is the type of FromDate? What is the value of FromDate?
Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Language is VB, error message is Addon Failed with exception, Event type=7 Matrix defined like this Dim mtx2 As SAPbouiCOM.Matrix
                    mtx2 = DirectCast(SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("1_U_G").Specific, SAPbouiCOM.Matrix) variable defined like this Dim FromDate As String value is 2019/07/23

Answer (score 0):

I did it. I converted variable instead of field of query
Thank you